# svcutil, wcf service, xml serialization failed to deserialize one field

Tags: c#, wcf, xml-serialization

I use svcutil (version "4.6.1055.0") to generate proxy classes for a wcf service

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=2)]
public string permitCode
{
    get
    {
        return this.permitCodeField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.permitCodeField = value;
    }
}
```

but after I call the service, in the deserialized object, all other fields are ok, but one field (permitCode) is empty, while in the soap response in fiddler that field has value.

Any idea why only this field failed to be deserialized? Or how can I debug it?

Comment: Can you share the XML that fails to deserialize?  One possibility is that the missing element is in the wrong order, as you have explicitly specified [`XmlElementAttribute.Order`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.order%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry I cannot provide more details of the XML. But the order is correct. The name, type, order, everything seems correct, and that's the only field that's not mapped. Just wondering how can I debug it?

Comment: 1) You could add a listener to [`XmlSerializer.UnknownElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.unknownelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  2) You could create an instance of your class programmatically, serialize it, and compare the generated XML with the XML from the service to check for discrepancies.  3) [Troubleshooting Common Problems with the XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302290.aspx) has some useful advice.